# Custom field in flex bar chart

Tags: apache-flex, bar-chart

I am using floating bar charts to represent schedule in flex. Data is defined like this:

```
public var schedule:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
            {task:"task1",start:6,end:9},
            {task:"task2",start:11,end:12},
            {task:"task3",start:14,end:17}
        ]);
```

start and end here stands for the time that task begins and finishes.
My question is the xField (time) always start from 0, so that I will have quite a large empty space and the chart doesn't look nice. I want it start from 6, as the start time of task "task1". How can I do it? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Just use the properties "minimum" and "maximum" of LinearAxis. To get the actual min und max values you can search them in the data provider.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
           minWidth="955" minHeight="600" creationComplete="init()">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        [Bindable]public var schedule:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
            {task:"task1", start:6, end:9},
            {task:"task2", start:11, end:12},
            {task:"task3", start:14, end:17}
        ]);

        [Bindable]private var minTime:Number = 24;
        [Bindable]private var maxTime:Number = 0;

        protected function init():void
        {
            for each (var task:Object in schedule)
            {
                if (task.start < minTime)
                    minTime = task.start;

                if (task.end > maxTime)
                    maxTime = task.end;
            }
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<mx:BarChart 
    dataProvider="{schedule}" 
    showDataTips="true">
    <mx:verticalAxis>
        <mx:CategoryAxis 
            dataProvider="{schedule}" 
            categoryField="task"/>
    </mx:verticalAxis>
    <mx:horizontalAxis>
        <mx:LinearAxis minimum="{minTime}" maximum="{maxTime}"/>
    </mx:horizontalAxis>
    <mx:series>
        <mx:BarSeries 
            xField="end"
            minField="start"/>
    </mx:series>
</mx:BarChart>
</s:Application>
```